# Why do I get an md5 hash mismatch when both strings being compared are identical?

Tags: c#, json, hash, md5

I am working on a C# program that uses md5 hashing. A file is created using an older version of the program and the hash is saved in a field in the file. Here is a code snippet showing the saving of the hash and the file:

```
using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
{
     this.Hash = string.Empty;
     s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
     string hash = MD5hash.GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, s);
     this.Hash = hash;
     s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
 }
```

The string "s" is saved to a file in JSON format and "this" is the object that is serialized.

In a new version of the program I am attempting to load the above file but the md5 hashes don't match even though I compare the files and they are identical. Here is a snippet:

```
using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
{
     hash = MD5hash.GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, s);
     if (fhash == hash)
     {
         return f;
     }
     else
     {
         throw new Exception("HashMismatch");
     }
 }
```

"fhash" is loaded from the file and is the hash that was saved in the older version. Since "s" in the the new version in the above code matches "s" in the older version "hash" and "fhash" should match but they don't. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Debugging tip: You could check if the bytes are the same for both inputs. Maybe there is a newline/encoding difference.

Comment: I'd imagine that by simply checking the JSON strings you would see the problem immediately. Try adding `[JsonIgnore]` on your `hash` property.

Answer (score 3):

In the first block of code you generate a hash from the object that has a hash of `string.empty` but in the second block you are attempting to generate a hash from the file which was serialized with the `Hash` property set to the generated hash.

So when you generate the hash for the loaded file it will generate a different value because the `Hash` property is no longer the same value that was used when generated the original hash i.e. `string.empty`.

When you load the file in the second block of code you need to set the `Hash` property to `string.empty` to get the hashes to match.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and my apologies for failing to mention that I am doing this is the full program but failed to mention it in the snippet.

Comment: @Vivek It might be the "full program" in terms of code that executes, but it's not a [mcve]. The only way I can test your code is if I make a guess at what the class it runs in looks like. Either way, the reason is pretty clear in this case.